# Is Pandas not importing? 'NameError: global name 'pandas' is not defined'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning

I'm getting a few errors here but I think it's due to pandas not importing as it's greyed out. If that is the problem, how would I fix this?

> C:\Anaconda\python.exe
>   C:/Users/nickd/Documents/SKLEARN-STOCKS/stock-mach.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/nickd/Documents/SKLEARN-STOCKS/stock-mach.py", line 38, in
>   
>       Key_Stats()   File "C:/Users/nickd/Documents/SKLEARN-STOCKS/stock-mach.py", line 12, in
>   Key_Stats
>       df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Ticker','DE Ratio']) NameError: global name 'pandas' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

#location of the data files
path = 'C:\Users\nickd\Documents\SKLEARN-STOCKS'
#what specific field do you want to grab and in all files in that directory
def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq) "):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Ticker','DE Ratio'])

    for each_dir in stock_list[1:5]:
        each_file = os.listdir(each_dir)
        ticker = each_dir.split("//")[1]
        if len(each_file) >0:
            for file in each_file:

                date_stamp = datetime.strptime(file, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.html')
                #unix_time = time.mktime(date_stamp.timetuple())
                print(date_stamp,unix_time)
                full_file_path = each_file+'/'+file
                #print(full_file_path)
                source = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()
                #print(source)
                try:
                    value = float(source.split(gather+':</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0])
                    df = df.append({'Date':date_stamp,'Unix':unix_time,'Ticker':ticker,'DE Ratio':value,}, ignore_index = True)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

                #print(ticker+":",value)

    save = gather.replace(' ','').replace(')','').replace('(','').replace('/',''+('.csv')
    print(save)
    df.to_csv(save)

                #time.sleep(15)

Key_Stats()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have imported it as

```
import pandas as pd
```

and calling

```
#pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Ticker','DE Ratio'])
```

You could either change

- `import pandas as pd` to `import pandas` or
- `df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Ticker','DE Ratio'])` to `df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Ticker','DE Ratio'])`.

**edit:**

error is due to missing `)`

```
save = gather.replace(' ','').replace(')','').replace('(','').replace('/',''+('.csv'))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I'm really new to python (and coding outsite of HTML) so appreciate the example.

I made the "pd.DataFrame"  and I'm not getting the below error. Which I confusing because I thought I set the save function above.

_C:\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/nickd/Documents/SKLEARN-STOCKS/stock-mach.py
  File "C:/Users/nickd/Documents/SKLEARN-STOCKS/stock-mach.py", line 36
    print(save)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1_

Comment: Thanks!! I've got terrible eyes :) That's it working now!

Comment: @NickDuddy if this solved your question can you accept the answer by ticking the right sign

Answer (score 1):

You imported pandas as `pd`. Either refer to it as such throughout, or remove the `as pd` from the import.

(Plus, **never ever ever** do `except Exception... pass`. You'll swallow all sorts of errors and never know what they were. If you aren't going to handle them, don't catch them at all.)